# Conditions for existence of a limit of a ratio of two integrals

Tags: integration, limits, probability-distributions

Let $g(\cdot,\cdot) \geq 0 $ be continuous, $f(x) > 0$ a bounded continuous density and thus the corresponding CDF $F(x) = \int^x f(t)dt$ strictly increasing. Consider the following limit: $$\underset{z\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\frac{\int g(x,F(-z x))f(-z x)dx}{\int g(x,F(z x))f(z x)dx}$$

I want to find minimal (sufficient) conditions for the existence of the limit. It can be infinite. Preferably, conditions should be on $f$ and $F$ and not on $g$, i.e. $g$ is neither monotonic nor bounded nor constant.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Kind of strange to have a limit where $\epsilon$ (a symbol reserved for small quantities) goes to $\infty$...

Comment: Thank you for the remark, notation updated.

Comment: Are there really no limits at those integrals? So you mean the antiderivative or do you mean a Riemann Integral?

Comment: The integrals are lebesque, i.e. over the support of the random variable $x$ with CDF $F$ that is the whole real line. I am not looking for the antiderivative(s).

Answer (score 2):

It holds for $z>0$ with $y = -zx$ with 
\begin{align*}\int_{-\infty}^\infty g\left(x,F(-zx)\right) f(-zx)\; dx &= \int_{\infty}^{-\infty} g\left(-\frac{y}{z},F(y)\right) f(y) \left(-\frac{1}{z}\right)\; dy \\&= \frac{1}{z} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g\left(-\frac{y}{z},F(y)\right) f(y)\; dy\end{align*}

and with $y = zx$

\begin{align*}\int_{-\infty}^\infty g\left(x,F(zx)\right) f(zx)\; dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g\left(\frac{y}{z},F(y)\right) f(y) \frac{1}{z}\; dy \\&= \frac{1}{z} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g\left(\frac{y}{z},F(y)\right) f(y)\; dy\end{align*}

Hence
\begin{align*}\frac{\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,F(-z x))f(-z x)dx}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,F(z x))f(z x)dx} &= \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g\left(-\frac{y}{z},F(y)\right) f(y)\; dy}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g\left(\frac{y}{z},F(y)\right) f(y)\; dy} \\\\&= \frac{E\left[g\left(\frac{Y}{z},F_Y(Y)\right)\right]}{E\left[g\left(-\frac{Y}{z},F_Y(Y)\right)\right]}\end{align*}

(just indexed $F$ by $Y$ to make clear that $F$ depends of $Y$ and vice versa)

for a suitable r.v. $Y$

So you want to know if $$\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{E\left[g\left(\frac{Y}{z},F_Y(Y)\right)\right]}{E\left[g\left(-\frac{Y}{z},F_Y(Y)\right)\right]}$$
exists for certain r.v. $Y$

I doubt that this is possible without any additional restrictions on $g$.

E.g. if $Y$ is bounded the limit exists iff $E[g(0,F_Y(Y))] \not= 0$.

This can be seen as a restriction on $Y$ but also one to $g$.